# Regex extracting first part and table name then adding second part as information

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to use Regex to separate a column that has a specific delimitator. The field contains as an example below where the e.g. `User ID` should become the column name and then separated by `:` and ends with `|` for that specific column, however this might have different lengths. Here is the example column:

```
User ID : '1090affb-4f54-4f12-b47f-57a94ab4ce0d' | User Name : 'Lee76@gmail.com' | Rma : '12929311' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : '6398b7f3-f248-497e-bb5b-7ecf86833255' | User Name : 'rud41@gmail.com' | Rma : '12985811' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : 'f7602cee-35ae-444f-a955-5f41c1babe1c' | User Name : 'carinak65@gmail.com' | Rma : '14626311' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : '07177e26-d4af-4302-9c4b-feb68087103b' | User Name : 'berghcea3@gmail.com' | Rma : '12511156' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : '6b904713-3fad-464f-baed-f6ea48ee7aab' | User Name : 'hesterafzee@gmail.com' | Rma : '10611503' | T&C Version : '2' | Abc : '252314620'
User ID : 'c4600019-71cb-4f37-a873-48c1f31dc4b2' | User Name : 'faricwl@gmail.com' | Rma : '12511714' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : '6cb88928-4856-4d47-a155-74b6d760b1cf' | User Name : 'piena331@gmail.com' | Rma : '12811759' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : '200694d3-da0f-4154-9000-0024ac451aad' | User Name : 'Andrea.ze@gmx.de' | Rma : '11165338' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : 'd78bb37a-756f-48f9-b654-b9d459ae03b6' | User Name : 'mwians@gmail.com' | Rma : '12116265' | T&C Version : '2'
User ID : 'ef7419ba-361b-45f9-bf7a-37d98f129fad' | User Name : 'kawayalen567@gmail.com' | Rma : '12112914' | T&C Version : '2'
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to get an output like:

```
User ID
1090affb-4f54-4f12-b47f-57a94ab4ce0d

User Name
Lee76@gmail.com

Rma
12929311

T&C Version
2
```

I tried the following, however it is too specific and would like to get it more generic focusing only on the split indicators:

```
^User\sID\s:\s'[A-Za-z0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]*'\s\|\sUser\sName\s:\s'[A-Za-z0-9]*@*
```

Here is also the example I tried:

```
https://regex101.com/r/8SsA6G/1
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: I added what I tired in the questions above, it is however too specific, I do not know how I can split the items by : and | irrespective of the length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
^(User\sID)\s:\s'([^']*)'\s\|\s(User\sName)\s:\s'([^']+)'\s\|\s(Rim)\s:\s'([^']*)'\s\|\s(T&C\sVersion)\s:\s'([^']+)'$
```

with:

```
\1\n\2\n\n\3\n\4\n\n\5\n\6\n\n\7\n\8\n\n
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/9ITQzr/1

Notice that:

- `[^']` means any character that is not a `'`
- `(...)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and you reference it with `\1`, `\2`, etc. (or `$1`, `$2`, etc., depending on the language)

---

EDIT: a generic solution can be to replace:

```
([^:]+?)\s:\s'([^']*)'(?:\s\|\s|$)?
```

with:

```
\1\n\2\n\n
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/TGVwso/1

Comment: Thank you very much horcrux it is exactly what I was looking for.